# PyCharm: Unresolved reference for StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Python 3.6

I am using `tkinter` to program the game Mastermind. However I struggle due to an unresolved reference for my `number1` in the function `Check`.

```
def Check(event):
    number1 = number1.get()
    number2 = str(number1)

def Enter(event):
    number1 = StringVar()
    entry_1 = Entry(window, textvariable = number1)
    entry_1.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    entry_1.focus()
    entry_1.bind("<Return>", Check)
```

Here my Error Message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Colbach/Google Drive/Charlotte/Informatique/Projet/Mastermind.py", line 39, in Check
    number1 = number1.get()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit more informations ? Mainly the error thrown, along with a stacktrace. You could give your python and  tkinter version too. I guess your error comes from the undefined `number1` in `number1.get()`

Comment: @CharlotteColbach 
Edit your question and add there the error message and provide [mcve]

Comment: You create a local variable `number1` (left side of equation). On the right side of the equation you try to use this variable before it is defined.

Comment: Main point: You can't access a variable that is local in another function,

Comment: I now tried to replace my Enter function by a for-loop (So now the variable is not defined in another function) but it still is not working :(

Comment: this `number1 = number1.get()` should probably be that: `number1 = entry1.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have mixed up two variable names:

this `number1 = number1.get()` should probably be that: `number1 = entry1.get()`